# show Multi InfoBubble on the multi MapMarker Here Map android?

Tags: android, here-api

In here.com map class MapMarker to this method showInfoBubble () not possible to show multi info bubble on the multi map markers is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaDoc for [`showInfoBubble`](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapmarker.html#topic-apiref__showinfobubble-void) method:

> As only one info bubble can be displayed on the map at a time, thus when calling showInfoBubble() on a different MapMarker, the current info bubble on display will automatically be closed before the newly selected one is shown.

So multiple info bubbles are not supported by the SDK. To achieve this additional code will have to be written by the application.

Edit: As mentioned by Marco in the comments, the `showInfoBubble` method is deprecated in favor of the [`MapOverlay`](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapoverlay.html#topic-apiref) class.

Comment: Check out https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapoverlay.html since this is what you want. You can define your own views and stick it to geopositions on the map, so exactly what the infobubble should do.

Comment: thanks, is example code available for this issue or solution

Comment: @AndrewJC Hi, Is there any effect on android app performance if we use `MapOverlay` class instead `InfoBubble`? Because I want to show multiple info bubbles at a time on each marker.

Comment: @RoyMiller I wouldn't be able to say for sure without prototyping and profiling. I would suggest you create an MVP prototype of your use case and profile to ensure performance is acceptable.